# attempting to trigger a submit on entered digits equal to 11

Tags: angularjs

I am attempting to trigger a submit call automatically when ever the entered digits in a `textarea` is equal to 11. Here is my attempt

```js
$scope.test = function() {
  if ($scope.name.length >= 11) {
    //submit the form
  }
}
```

```html
<form>
  <input ng-model="name" ng-change="test()" type="text">
</form>
```

Comment: Please pass ng-model value to your ng-change function directly then handle it accordingly.

Comment: what do you mean by "submit"? What are you trying to do after your if statement is triggered?

Comment: What happens of the user continues typing? Will the submit happen multiple times? What if the user makes a typo? Will the form submit before the use has a chance to correct it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `ng-change` and can check the `length`.

Then You can use, `$scope.name.length` in controller

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.9/angular.min.js"></script>

<body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">

<form ng-submit="myFunc()">
  <input ng-model="name" ng-change="test()" type="text">
</form>
<p>{{myTxt}}</p>
<script>
var app = angular.module("myApp", []);
app.controller("myCtrl", function($scope) {
$scope.name;
  $scope.myTxt = "You have not yet clicked submit";
  $scope.test = function () {
   
        if($scope.name && $scope.name.toString().length >= 11){
        
        $scope.myFunc();
        }
        
  }
  $scope.myFunc = function () {
    alert('submitted');
      $scope.myTxt = "You clicked submit!";
  }
});
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

**Please run the above snippet**

Answer (score 0):

You can try like the below code, also check [this plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/3zcOypHjrhcRCVMLHYAM?p=preview) link for your example scenario.

**Template:**

```
<textarea ng-model="name" maxlength="11" ng-change="test(name)" type="text"></textarea>
```

**Controller:**

```
app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.test = function (name) {
    if(name.length == 11){
      alert(name);
    }
  };
});
```

**Note:** You can have http call instead of alert. And please do not forget to inject **$scope** into your controller.